# Maximum function nesting level Using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

so I started to use Laravel auth and in my Route in web middleware I wrote :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::auth();
});
```

and I got this error :

```
Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!
```

and I tried to use this instead :

```
Route::auth();
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {...});
```

and then when I wanted to use old function in my form I got this error

```
Session store not set on request.
```

can you help me , a tutorial link is also a good idea :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem of recursion. So,go into your `php.ini` configuration file and change the following line:

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level=100
```

to something like:

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level=200
```

**Edit:**

If you are using wamp then please comment

```
 zend_extension = "d:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.8/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.1.2-5.3-vc9.dll //here wamp is installed in d drive.
```

in my `php.ini` file. This extension should be  limiting the stack to 100 .

Comment: @MohammadReza which os are you using ? Also, are you using wamp ??

Comment: windows , yes wamp

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by adding this line in bootstrap/autoload.php

```
ini_set('xdebug.max_nesting_level', 200);
```